# Matlab - calculate curvature along an ordered perimeter

Tags: matlab, math, contour

I found a little mathematical expression to find the curvature along an ordered perimeter. I get that ordered perimeter using the function `bwboundaries`.

To use it I start to define three coordinates p1,p2 and p3 which are column vectors x,y.

```
    % the part above extract the three coordinates into row vectors y,x.
    % That's why I flip and transpose them.

    p1=outlineCoords(i,:);
    p2=outlineCoords2;
    p3=outlineCoords3;

    p1 = fliplr(p1);
    p2 = fliplr(p2);
    p3 = fliplr(p3);

    p1 = p1.';
    p2 = p2.';
    p3 = p3.';
```

Here is the mathematical expression :

```
curVec(i) = 2*det([p1-p3,p2-p1])/(norm(p1-p3)*norm((p2-p1)*norm(p2-p3)));
```

I don't like using things that I don't understand. I think that for each point of my contour it fits a circle through p1,p2 and p3 and take the inverse of the radius but I don't understand why it gives me the curvature...

I draw the curvature with a color code going from blue to red.

[image: draw of the curvature with a color code]

Somebody could help me to understand better what I'm dealing with !?

Thank you !

Comment: what are p1 p2 and p3? Are they just 3 contiguous points in the boundary?

Comment: " I found a little mathematical expression" where? probably it has a good explanation wherever you found it.

Comment: p1,p2 and p3 are 3 contiguous points in the boundary yes ! And no there is no explanation at all;.. That's why I asked.

Comment: Where did you find it? **show us**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vector calculus curvature is related to the second derivative. The first being the tangent. You would have to reverse that equation in mysterious ways to show it's derivation; which I cannot do. But I have however arrived at that and other similar formulas several times based on what I already know curvature to be.

Here is the calculus notes on the topic. You see it is very similar to your equation:

[Calculus III - Curvature](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Curvature.aspx)